# How to control an flash nested movie clip instance with buttons situated in different movie clip (Action Script 2.0)?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am working on an Action Script 2.0 based Flash file. I was trying to control a movieclip instance named "Xyz" which is located in a different object.

I used:

```
[code]_root.gotoAndPlay(4)[/code]
```

Now my question is how to control a flash nested movie clip instance with buttons situated in different movie clip.

The code I mentioned above takes me to the very start/root of the main animation. Where I just want to deal with a particular movieclip.

I have assigned a label to that movie clip as "XYZ", but I could not find a way to call this object and play/show particular frame.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `mcChild` nested inside `mcParent`, which is situated on the main timeline. To control `mcChild` from the main timeline (or `_root`), you can do the following:

```
mcParent.mcChild.gotoAndStop(3);
```

In your case, you'd need to do this:

```
parentInstanceName.Xyz.gotoAndStop(2); //2 is just an example, of course.
```

**But, for this to work, you need to assign an instance name to the movieclip that contains the `Xyz` movieclip.**

Also, this works for multiple levels of nesting. e.g. `mc1.mc2.mc3.gotoAndStop(5);`